# Live wallpaper with image change on Time interval

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I want an live wallpaper example which uses image to set wallpaper and handle orientation change also. I want to set time interval of say 30 seconds after which the next image will be displayed in wallpaper. i Checked few tutorial like vogela's but it doesn't use image. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have u tried some where? means where is your code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Timer class for the the interval issue and for orientation change i reflected the changes in onSurfaceChanged() method of WallpaperService.

Comment: can you help me how you did this?